# Nested function inside a function with begin/process/end blocks?

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to have a nested function inside a function containing begin/process/end blocks? The first error reported is:

```
begin : The term 'begin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if 
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\src\cut\f1.ps1:13 char:5
+     begin { Write-Verbose "initialize stuff" }
+     ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (begin:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Here is the code in question.

```
function f1 (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [array]$Content
        ,[Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipeline=$false, Position=0)]
        [string[]]$Path
)
{
    function a([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$s)
    {
        "=== a === $s"
    }

    begin { Write-Verbose "initialize stuff" }
    process {
        Write-Verbose "process stuff"
        a($Content)
    }
    end { Write-Verbose "end stuff" }
}

Get-Content -Path 'C:\src\cut\cut-man.txt' | f1 -Path '.\cut-man.txt'
```

The function may have a dozen or more parameters. If I cannot nest the function, I will need to create another function and duplicate passing the parameters or use global variables. I do not want to use global variables if possible. How can this be done?

Comment: Can't test right now but can you put that declaration inside the begin block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible to create nested function but you must stick with the structure of the function section which is like this:

```
function ()
{
   param()
   begin{}
   process{}
   end{}
}
```

you cant write anything between param,begin,process and end sections. so to write your second function you have two options. 1- you can write the second function outside the first function and it works like magic. 2- if you need to test the option of nested functions, you can write your second function either in begin section or in the start of the process section as following:

```
function f1 (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string]$Content
        ,[Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipeline=$false, Position=0)]
        [string[]]$Path
)
{
    begin 
    { 
        Write-Verbose "initialize stuff" 
        function a([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$s)
        {
            "=== a === $s"
        }
    }
   process 
    {   
        Write-Verbose "process stuff"
        a($Content)   
    }
    end 
    { 
        Write-Verbose "end stuff" 
    }
}

Get-Content -Path 'C:\src\cut\cut-man.txt' | f1 -Path '.\cut-man.txt'  -Verbose
```

Comment: Wonderful! I was thinking that the `process` and `end` blocks would be out of scope for a function in the `begin` block. Apparently they can see and use it. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, the `[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$s` will not accept a zero-length string. I removed `[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]` and it appears to be working.

Comment: This is weird. Variables created in the `begin` block are in scope inside the `process` and `end` scriptblocks.